# Calling template function inside another one but for function returning template type

Tags: c++

I cannot understand why I can't build this code:

```
template<typename T> T* func ( void )
{
    return NULL;
}

template<typename T> T* func2 ( void )
{
    T* var = func();
    return NULL;
}
```

Compilation result is: "error: no matching function for call to ‘func()’"
The code below is fine:

```
template<typename T> void func ( T var )
{
    return;
}

template<typename T> void func2 ( T var )
{
    func( var );
}
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are only showing part of your error message.  Clang would add `candidate template ignored:  couldn't infer template argument 'T'`.  GCC would add `note: candidate: 'template<class T> T* func()'  couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'`.  Those notes are describing what is wrong.

Comment: you do not need a function template calling another function template to have the same issue. Suppose there is no `func1`, how would you call `func2`? Or try to call `func1` outside of `func2`

Comment: @DrewDormann, yes the problem was presented by compiler but unfortunately this message doesn't show how to solve the problem. I'm not advanced in C++ enough to deduce the solution basing on that message.

Comment: actually it does. Error messages are hard to read when you are new to them, but with some practice the error message holds lots of hints on how to fix it. Thats why you better include the complete error message in the question. If you don't understand, others can explain

Comment: @Mikolaj it looks like your problem is solved.  Great!  When asking about future compiler errors, it would benefit you to show the _complete_ error message.  Your full error message here told you that the template argument was not supplied and could not be inferred/deduced by the compiler.

Comment: @Mikolaj - Template argument deduction is pretty advanced in itself. If you are learning about that, the knowledge about return types should have been already presented. If you are experimenting to learn without a good learning resource, then know that C++ is very bad for learning by trial and error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler needs to be able to determine the template parameter by some means. The type occurs in the function parameter list, the compiler often can deduce the type parameter based on the parameter passed. In the second example this is possible, since you pass `var` to `func` in `func2`.

If the functions do not take any function parameters, there's no way for the compiler to tell which template parameter to use without you explicitly specifying it, e.g.

```
template<typename T> T* func()
{
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename T> T* func2()
{
    T* var = func<T>();
    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Templates aren't like generics in Java. Templates create multiple *different* versions of functions

```
template<typename T> T* func ( void )
{
    return NULL;
}
```

This is *not* a declaration of one function. It's a declaration of an infinite class of functions. When you write `func()`, C++ has no idea which one to call. In this particular case, it doesn't matter since they all return `NULL`, but in general it absolutely does. In your parameterized version, you take a parameter of type `T`, so when you call it, C++ is smart enough to see that the `T` must match the parameter's type, and it knows which one to call. That is, it converts `func(var)` to `func<T>(var)` for you.

If you want to call your 0-ary version, you need to give it an explicit type argument.

```
// Valid
func<int>();
func<double>();
func<T>(); // Assuming T is a template parameter in-scope
// Invalid (ambiguous)
func();
```